# Is a "drag-multi-select" type of selection on multiple Views possible in React Native?

Tags: react-native, multi-select

Summary:

- Tried the Gesture Responder system [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/gesture-responder-system), but I can't seem to figure out how to select the element currently under the user's touch. After tons of experiementing, it seems that this is not possible. (?)
- Where I'm stuck at: [Many Views in a grid-style layout that should support drag-multi-select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaY0k.png)
- What I want to achieve: Something similar to [when2meet](https://www.when2meet.com/)
- Current using React Native with Expo

Comment: Are you using flatlist or something ?

Comment: @DipanSharma Thanks for asking. I am using ScrollView.

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453340/enable-dragging-of-element-in-a-scrollview-after-long-press

Comment: @DipanSharma I might have been unclear what effect I wanted. I am not looking to drag views around, but instead something like this https://youtu.be/ythOIDjUko0?t=101 (from 1:42 to 1:45) where the user can drag to select multiple items at once. Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? Currently stuck with this problem on react native with expo as well